# Probability distribution function / Line of best fit

Tags: python, statistics, probability-distribution

I have [data](https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/explore/dataset/pedestrian-counting-system-monthly-counts-per-hour/table/?sort=timestamp&location=15,-37.81012,144.95221&basemap=mbs-7a7333) about pedestrian counts from multiple sensors along a street. I know the location of each sensor. Assume that the street has total length L.

I want a function F(l,t) that gives pedestrian counts given a length l (along the street)and a time t. The graph below shows pedestrian counts from various sensors (in a single street) within 0 to L, i want to map the distribution to the function described. I have data about pedestrian counts over a 24hr for multiple days/hourly data. What is the best way to get the line of best fit that gives F? What python library should I use to get this for my data.

Note about the dataset:
The column total directions gives total number of pedestrians passing the sensor at that hour.

[the graph of total pedestrians over a day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8kEl.png)

[sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQrSA.png)

Comment: The question is kind of confusing. It is hard to understand what data you have and what the function F is supposed to return. You mention searching for the line of best fit, are you trying to fit a curve to each of the swa sensor data record you have plotted in the graph? If thats the case, I suggest you try a polynomial regression (second order may be enougth). If not, try refining your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Agriseld I added the data reference, F should return the total pedestrian count at give l along a street and a time t.  For example i want to know the total pedestrian count 25feet (on a street) and at 12pm. I am thinking it should be a probability distribution function https://www.scribbr.com/statistics/probability-distributions/